# How to add c# custom controls to MonoDevelop toolbox?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk#, zedgraph

I am new to mono develop, I created a gtk# 2.0 project in Mono Develop and tried to add C# user defined controls like Zedgraph, but the toolbox is not accepting c# user-defined controls. Is there a way to add C# user defined controls to Mono Develop toolbox. Anyone please help me.

Comment: Which MonoDevelop version?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I can not see the Zedgraph widgets in the toolbox...but I can add widgets via the code. So instead of going into "designer" view and do it via GUI, you could do it via the "Source" view. (after you add the dll to your references).

I hope somebody has a better solution.